# How to make hyperref destination names unique, to make TOC links work?

Tags: table-of-contents, hyperref

The circumstances of this question are somewhat unlike the results I got from searching the error message on my own.

```
[20]LuaTeX warning (ext4): destin
ation with the same identifier (name{subsection.1.2.1}) has been already used,
duplicate ignored
```

Basically, I *want* duplicate section names, and the error is... not erroneous, I just need a way to make the destination names unique, so the TOC clicky links work.

Here's the MWE which should explain what is going on.

```
% main.tex

\documentclass[12pt]{article}

\usepackage{tocloft}
\usepackage{regexpatch}
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\usepackage[newparttoc]{titlesec}

\usepackage[pdfencoding=auto,plainpages=false,pdfpagelabels,psdextra]{hyperref}
\usepackage{bookmark}
\usepackage{fontspec, xunicode, microtype}

\makeatletter
    \def\@seccntformat#1{\protect\makebox[0pt][r]{\csname
    the#1\endcsname\quad}}
\makeatother

\makeatletter
\patchcmd{\@part}% <cmd>
  {\markboth{}{}}% <search>
  {\partmark{#1}}% <replace>
  {}{}% <success><failure>
\makeatother


\makeatletter
    \@addtoreset{section}{part}
\makeatother

\cftpagenumbersoff{part}

\title{Test}

\begin{document}
\pagenumbering{gobble}

% titlepage

\begin{center}

A Title

\end{center}

% end title page


\pagebreak
\tableofcontents
\pagebreak

\hypersetup{pageanchor=true}
\pagenumbering{arabic}


% would be \input{"test1"}, but it doesn't matter

\pagebreak
\part{Part One}
\section{To Slice a Hotdog}
    \subsection{Operating a Knife}
        Foo Bar.


\renewcommand{\thepart}{\Alph{part}}

\pagebreak
\begin{center}Addendums\end{center}
\pagebreak

\setcounter{part}{0}
% would be \input{"addendums"}, but again, doesn't change things

\pagebreak
\part{Addendum One}
\section{To Blend a Hotdog}
    \subsection{Operating a Blender}
        Something something.

\end{document}
```

I'm *aware* that the reason I get these errors is due to me resetting the part number counter. The document I have has the first part with sections numbered numerically, ie. 1-9, etc. The next part, which is sort of an appendix but more of an addendum, is ordered A-Z. Hence I reset the counter and set the numbering to `\Alph`.

Of course, if there is a better way do accomplish what I want to achieve without resetting the counter and getting all these problems, that works too.

The appearance of those in the TOC is fine, but clicking on the item ever only brings me to the first section, which is understandable, of course. That's what I'm trying to solve.

From what I've gathered, I need to attack this macro: `\HyperDestNameFilter`. I've lost the original StackOverflow answer that recommended this, but I first tried `\renewcommand*{\HyperDestNameFilter}[1]{\jobname-#1}`, only to realise that since my files are `\input`ed into a main file, the jobname will be the same.

Then, I tried using `\renewcommand*{\HyperDestNameFilter}[1]{\thepage-#1}`. On first glance, that seems to work, in that I don't get the error anymore.

However, upon compiling all the pages, I get a *whole bunch*, and I mean *a whole bunch*, of these:

```
LuaTeX warning (dest): name{-subsubsection.1.3.3.3} has been referenced but does
 not exist, replaced by a fixed one

LuaTeX warning (dest): name{-subsubsection.1.3.3.2} has been referenced but does
 not exist, replaced by a fixed one

LuaTeX warning (dest): name{-subsubsection.1.3.3.1} has been referenced but does
 not exist, replaced by a fixed one

LuaTeX warning (dest): name{-subsection.1.3.3} has been referenced but does not 
exist, replaced by a fixed one

LuaTeX warning (dest): name{-subsection.1.3.2} has been referenced but does not 
exist, replaced by a fixed one
```

It goes on and on, and I think it's for every section, subsection, subsubsection, everything. Now, all the headings in my TOC simply bring me to the last page when clicked. *All* the links become broken. Help?

TL;DR, then: how do I make it so that I get unique destination names, so my TOC links will work properly even when I have identical section headings with the same number?

Thanks so much.

Comment: What shall we do with this list of packages? Most of them is completely unrelated to the problem.The last resort method is `hypertexnames=false` as an option to `hyperref` or `hypersetup`, but you have not shown the real cause of the problem!

Comment: Hello –– I'm not sure what the "real cause" of the problem is. I fully expect the error about duplicate names, I'm looking for a way to deduplicate them.

Also good point about the packages, I'll remove the irrelevant ones.

Comment: The cause are identical section etc. numbers -- this confuses `hyperref`. There's a remedy, however ;-)  Just show the compilable code that produces the wrong links, that should be enough.

Comment: The error is not about duplicate *titles*, it doesn't matter that your section title "To Slice a Hotdog" appears twice. You have two subsection numbered `1.2.1` and you need to show us how you did this.

Comment: Alright, I edited the question with a proper MWE, I kinda left out the crucial bit previously.

EDIT: I'm of course open to suggestions on doing what I want to achieve without things like resetting the counter.

Comment: This is not a proper MWE, it is a bunch of snippets. Why are you resetting the part counter?

Comment: I believe the snippet can reproduce the issue I'm facing. As for *why* I'm doing it... The document I have has the first part with sections numbered numerically, ie. 1-9, etc. The next part, which is sort of an appendix but more of an addendum, is ordered A-Z. Hence I reset the counter and set the numbering to \Alph{}.

Comment: No I can't reproduce the issue with your snippet as I can't compile the snippet. And I won't spent my time to try to build a complete document. It is your problem so you will have to do the work to setup a sensible test document.

Comment: @zhiayang: I told you already about the multiple sections having the some counter values (regardless `\arabic` or `\alph`) -- this can be cured, but **not without help from your side**

Comment: By all means, remove the weird-looking `\setcounter{part}{0}` instruction and check if the problem persists.

Comment: @Mico I know that, I want my addendum parts to start counting at A, if I don't reset it then it starts at B or C or something, depending on how many preceding parts there were.

@UlrikeFischer, @ChristianHupfer Sorry, I went to sleep. The current snippet should be a proper MWE. (My setup uses multiple files, but it doesn't matter if it's `\input`ed or just pasted in the main file.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Resetting counters of the sectioning structure by hand **must** confuse `hyperref` since it generates anchors from the counter values.

E.g. a anchor name could be `part.1`.

However, this will appear again for the `Addendum` part, even if `\thepart` is redefined to be `\Alph{part}` -- the anchor name is generated of a special command named `\theHpart` etc. If this gets a new prefix, say `addendum` all should get well.

Thus

`\renewcommand{\theHpart}{addendum.\thepart}`

should provide the unique names.

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}

\usepackage{tocloft}

\usepackage{etoolbox}
\usepackage[newparttoc]{titlesec}
\usepackage{fontspec, microtype}
\usepackage[pdfencoding=auto,plainpages=false,pdfpagelabels,psdextra]{hyperref}
\usepackage{bookmark}


\makeatletter
    \def\@seccntformat#1{\protect\makebox[0pt][r]{\csname
    the#1\endcsname\quad}}
\makeatother

\makeatletter
\patchcmd{\@part}% <cmd>
  {\markboth{}{}}% <search>
  {\partmark{#1}}% <replace>
  {}{}% <success><failure>
\makeatother


\makeatletter
    \@addtoreset{section}{part}
\makeatother

\cftpagenumbersoff{part}

\title{Test}

\begin{document}
\pagenumbering{gobble}

% titlepage

\begin{center}

A Title

\end{center}

% end title page


\pagebreak
\tableofcontents
\pagebreak

\hypersetup{pageanchor=true}
\pagenumbering{arabic}


% would be \input{"test1"}, but it doesn't matter

\pagebreak
\part{Part One}
\section{To Slice a Hotdog}
    \subsection{Operating a Knife}
        Foo Bar.


\renewcommand{\thepart}{\Alph{part}}

\pagebreak
\begin{center}Addendums\end{center}
\pagebreak

\setcounter{part}{0}
\renewcommand{\theHpart}{addendum.\thepart}
% would be \input{"addendums"}, but again, doesn't change things

\pagebreak
\part{Addendum One}
\section{To Blend a Hotdog}
    \subsection{Operating a Blender}
        Something something.

\end{document}
```

Comment: Alright this worked, thanks. Didn't see `\theHpart` mentioned in my searches, didn't think to look at that.

Comment: @zhiayang: I told you in a comment it's easy ;-)

Comment: I'm not sure why you're loading `regexpatch`

Comment: @egreg: It was in the OP

Comment: @ChristianHupfer I see; well it's not needed; and `xunicode` should not be loaded.

Comment: @egreg: I am using a Tablet right now, with limited editing possibilities - I will change later on